# Multithreading JPArepository Bulk Insert

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jdbc, executorservice

A process I've been working on for a little while now. Process was running fine until the performance was taking a hit. I figured out a way to get it to perform very fast, but I'm really unsure what is happening behind the scenes. And it's now throwing warnings and errors and I'm not sure what to do. File is getting porocessed but I'm not sure if all threads are complete, and I don't believe I am shutting down the app correctly. Here is everything you need to know...

File is read using a buffered reader, we then run some data quality checks on each record, every record that is read and passes data quality checks we create a java object out of it and insert into a List. Once the List is 1000 objects big, we then call an OracleService class which has a Repo autowired and we execute a saveAll method with the List. We then continue to read the file and do this until the file is done being read. I am passing in, to the service, and ExecutorService object. So every time we call that service it is getting a new List object containing my objects (this object is basically the table we are loading) and a new ExecutorService Object. Process is running fine but getting a ton of exceptions being thrown once I try to shutdown. Here is all my code...

My Controller class run method. This will get called from another class which implements CommandLineRunner

```
    public void run() throws ParseException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("******************** Aegis Check Inclearing DDA Trial Balance Table Load starting ********************");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            int count = 0;
            TrialBalanceBuilder builder = new TrialBalanceBuilder();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("D")) {
                    if (dataQuality(line)) {
                        TrialBalance trialBalance = builder.buildTrialBalanceObject(line, procDt, time);
                        insertList.add(trialBalance);
                        count++;
                        if (count == 1000) {
                            oracleService.loadToTableTrialBalance(insertList, executorService);
                            count = 0;
                            insertList.clear();
                        }
                    } else {
                        logger.info("Data quality check FAILED for record: " + line);
                        oracleService.revertInserts("DDA_TRIAL_BAL_STG",procDt.toString());
                        System.exit(111);
                    }
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            logger.info("Leftover record count is " + insertList.size());
            oracleService.loadToTableTrialBalance(insertList, executorService);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logger.info("Updating Metadata table with new batch proc date");
        InclearingBatchMetadataBuilder inclearingBatchMetadataBuilder = new InclearingBatchMetadataBuilder();
        InclearingBatchMetadata inclearingBatchMetadata = inclearingBatchMetadataBuilder.buildInclearingBatchMetadataObject("DDA_TRIAL_BAL_STG", procDt, time, Constants.bankID);
        oracleService.insertBatchProcDtIntoMetaTable(inclearingBatchMetadata);
        logger.info("Successfully updated Metadata table with new batch proc date: " + procDt);

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        oracleService.cleanUpGOS("DDA_TRIAL_BAL_STG",1);

        executorService.shutdownNow();

        logger.info("******************** Aegis Check Inclearing DDA Trial Balance Table Load ended successfully ********************");
    }
```

I'm passing in an ExecutorService object to the service class. This is defined as...

```
    private final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Orders-%d").setDaemon(true).build();
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, threadFactory);
```

My service class looks as such....

```
@Service("oracleService")
public class OracleService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleService.class);

    @Autowired
    TrialBalanceRepo trialBalanceRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void loadToTableTrialBalance(List<TrialBalance> trialBalanceList, ExecutorService executorService) {
        logger.debug("Let's load to the database");
        logger.debug(trialBalanceList.toString());
        List<TrialBalance> multiThreadList = new ArrayList<>(trialBalanceList);
        try {
            executorService.execute(() -> trialBalanceRepo.saveAll(multiThreadList));
        } catch (ConcurrentModificationException | DataIntegrityViolationException ignored) {}
        logger.debug("Successfully loaded to database");
    }
```

In my run method i then call a few more methods in that Service class which create nativequeries and execute on the database (for purging etc.)

Anyway, I never know when the threads are complete. And I am finding in pre-production, when running with a lot of data, we shut down the app and not all the data is completely loaded. Also I don't know if this is even the best design. Do I keep passing in these executorservice objects? The whole point of this was to get optimal parallelism going so that our performance was better. Perhaps there is a better way (preferably without redesigning the entire app and using something other than JPA)

Comment: The beahviour you're describing here : "File is read using a buffered reader, we then run some data quality checks on each record, every record that is read and passes data quality checks we create a java object out of it and insert into a List. Once the List is 1000 objects big, we then call an OracleService class which has a Repo autowired and we execute a saveAll method with the List. We then continue to read the file and do this until the file is done being read." is definitely an loading `Batch` you should have a look into `Spring-Batch` and `Spring-Integration`.

Comment: @Zorglube I know. I really messed this up. There's no reason to have a Spring Boot application. I'm running this job from Control-M which is a batch job scheduler, it's calling a KSH script which runs a file reader and then we call the jar. The java code grabs a lot of environment variable from the shell session

Comment: Really look into Spring Batch Integration Configuration and so on, you'll get all the framework to buil an runnable `Jar` abble to grab all the env var you want AND able to read filter and write all the data you need whithout the PITA of handling the chuck size, the producer-consumer problem, the Jpa repo, the logging, the restart or resume, the running status, and so on...  If you want you build your own ETL or Batch engin, it's up to you pal.